# Не выходит изображение содержания формы: динамические объекты

Tags: delphi, bmp, скриншот

Выходят только статические объекты, а динамические - нет

А как сделать чтобы и изображение на форме выходило? У меня просто форма с контролями выходит, а все что там рисуется во время запуска не сохраняется.

**Дополнение(22.10.2013):** 
Я рисую на форме 3D объект с OpenGL (есть еще кнопки и другие контроли), мне нужно сделать скриншот этой формы с объектом, скриншот я делаю, но на выходном файле сохраняются только объекты формы, кнопки, текстбоксы, и т.д, а 3D объект с фоном не выходят. Как быть?

Comment: а как рисуете? в обработчике button click парой команд на канве Image? Тогда не будет работать.

Comment: Попробуйте задать вопрос человеческим языком. Что бы было понятно, что вы хотите сделать, что сделали, и что не получилось.